# Are the EV principles that are used in photography the same in video production?

Tags: video, camera

I am new to photography. I have been reading about the EV values and how to calculate them, with the f-stops, the shutter speed and ISO. However, I want to know if those same principles, tables and values apply not only for still photography, but for video shooting.

In summary, can I use the same tables that are used to calculate the EV (for still photography) for video shooting? Or do I have to take other variables into consideration (FPS etc.)

Thanks in advance

Marios

P.S. This is the original question I asked in the Photography forum of the site, I am reposting it here since a member of the other forum told me to post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  For things like exposure time, EV, f-stops, video is just the same as still photographs.  You just happen to be taking 24 or more of them per second.

The one difference in actually exposing a frame would be that still photography typically uses a mechanical shutter.  (You can hear it k'thwap when you take a picture on many cameras.)  But video uses an electronic shutter.  This could very slightly effect things like how motion blur looks, or how parts of the image are exposed over the course of the exposure time.  But that 99% doesn't matter, especially if you are just getting up to speed on the basics of things like f-stops.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!